# Live price update based on tier pricing

Tags: jquery, magento-1.9

We are using a tier pricing to offer better pricing based on quantity. By default if you type a quantity box the price doesn't change and remains static. So I would like the price to change and show the new price of the product if it hits a price tier.

ex. 
3 for 9.99 the price would dynamically change and show 3.33

5 for 15.99 the price would dynamically change and show 3.20

10 for 27.99 the price would dynamically change and show 2.80

Currently, I have the code dynamically changing. But whenever it changes it shows the whole price (ex. 9.99). I would like it to show the per item price rather than the whole price.

I'm using the following code:

```
var qty;
if($('qty').getValue().length==0 || isNaN($('qty').getValue()) || $('qty').getValue() <= 0) qty = 1;
  else qty = $('qty').getValue();
price*=qty; 
if (price > 0 || this.displayZeroPrice) {
   formattedPrice = this.formatPrice(price);
} else {
   formattedPrice = '';
}

if ($(pair.value).select('.price')[0]) {
$(pair.value).select('.price')[0].innerHTML = formattedPrice;
if ($(pair.value+this.duplicateIdSuffix) && $(pair.value+this.duplicateIdSuffix).select('.price')[0]) {
$(pair.value+this.duplicateIdSuffix).select('.price')[0].innerHTML = formattedPrice;
}
} else {
$(pair.value).innerHTML = formattedPrice;
if ($(pair.value+this.duplicateIdSuffix)) {
$(pair.value+this.duplicateIdSuffix).innerHTML = formattedPrice;
}
}
};
}.bind(this));
},
formatPrice: function(price) {
return formatCurrency(price, this.priceFormat);
}
}
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
if ($('qty')) $('qty') .observe('blur', function(e){
optionsPrice.reload();
});
});
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to try the examples, and ask a specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: None of them even work. I load the code and I see no change whatsoever.

Comment: This question is far too broad. SO is for specific code related problems. If you tried something that didn't work provide that code along with a proper problem statement related to it

Comment: I will rephrase my question and be more elaborate.